# Parsing HTML and counting tags with C#

Tags: c#, html, tags, count

Suppose I have a block of HTML in a string:

```
<div class="nav mainnavs">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">Questions</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-tags" href="/tags">Tags</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-users" href="/users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-badges" href="/badges">Badges</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-unanswered" href="/unanswered">Unanswered</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I parse the HTML and count the number of instances of a specific type of tag, such as `<div>` or `<li>`?

Comment: i like how you are using the stackoverflow navigation.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) for this - the latest version supports Linq so this is straight-forward:

**For a local html file:**

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"test.html");
int liCount = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li").Count(); //returns 5
```

**From the web:**

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://stackoverflow.com");
int liCount = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li").Count();
```